# change flagstrap selected item in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm using this plugin:

https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap

and I'm trying to change the currently selected country programmatically.
I've tried most of the common way we're used to apply on `select` controls.

Simple example:

```
<link href="http://blazeworx.com/flags.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://blazeworx.com/jquery.flagstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Country</label><br>
        <div class="flagstrap" id="select_country" data-input-name="input_country" data-selected-country=""></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_country').attr('data-selected-country','CN');
    $('#select_country').flagStrap();        
});
</script>
```

Now I want to change the selected country.
All the following don't work:

```
$('#select_country').attr('data-selected-country','IT');
$('#select_country :nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true); 
$('#select_country option:eq("IT")').prop('selected', true);  
$('#select_country option').eq("IT").prop('selected', true);
$("#select_country").val("IT");
$("#input_country").val("IT");
$('#select_country option[value="IT"]').prop('selected', true);
$('#select_country option')[3].selected = true;
$('#select_country option')["IT"].selected = true;
$("#select_country").val("IT").attr("selected", "selected");
$("#select_country option:first");
```

Comment: From checking the source I can see there's nowhere in the plugin code that handles what you need. The only thing you could do is to raise a `click` event on the required `a` element in the `.flagStrap` div. That gets handled on line 403: https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap/blob/master/src/jquery.flagstrap.js. I'd possibly suggest looking for a different library as not having that behaviour is a pretty big oversight.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Right now it would be enough to "reset" the plugin to the default state (i.e. no country selected). Do you think this can be easier? I'm thinking about remove an add again the `div` element...

Comment: The plugin has no `destroy()` or equivalent method, so the only way to do that would be to `clone()` the original `div`, then remove it, append the new one and instantiate the plugin again. It'd be simpler just to raise the `click` on the default option

Comment: Ok, I got it. If you might kindly provide a simple example you can write this as a solution, that I will accept.